# Excel for MacOS drops decimal separators when importing csv file

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, csv

I regularly work with csv files that use semicolons as the separator when I import these into Excel the decimal points are lost.

The values are displayed with the decimal place in the import wizard but once they are added to the sheet the decimal points disappear.

[You can see the import and the file in a text editor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88CXZ.png)

[Here you can see the import wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnGWR.png)

Is there any way to get Excel to recognize the decimal points? I've already tried changing the separators in the system settings.

I'm using macOS version 10.14.5 and Excel for Mac version 16.26

Comment: Your images do **not** show the import wizard ...

Comment: As far as Excel is concerned, a decimal separator separates the integer part of a number from the fractional part of a number.  There can be only one decimal separator.  "Punctuation" to make numbers more human readable (like thousands separators, currency signs, parentheses for negation, etc.) aren't part of the value as stored, they are formatting imposed later for display.  If you have numerical information containing what Excel interprets as formatting symbols, it discards the extraneous symbols.  (cont'd)

Comment: If Excel doesn't recognize the symbols and patterns as legitimate for a number, it interprets it as text.  If you want Excel to store those values unaltered, it will need to treat them as text strings.  If you have control over how the CSV is created, wrap each of those values in quotes.  If not, you will need to deal with it on the receiving end with some form of intervention to make Excel treat them as text.